# ¿Cómo convertir una lista json a diccionario en python?

Tags: python, json, diccionarios

¿Cómo convertir una lista de mensajes en formato json a una lista de diccionarios de manera automática en python?, esto con la finalidad d crear un df.

Estoy intentando crear un df en python pero antes, bajé la información que voy a necesitar en formato json, para poder convertirla un data frame, python me pide que lo convierta en diccionario para darle estructura y puedo hacerlo de forma manual pero son muchas conversaciones que tienen con los clientes, ya intenté con algo de código pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo de manera automática, este es un tramo de una conversación:

```
{'participants': [{'name': 'Abigail Jackeline CG'}, {'name': 'Magda Aguilar'}],
 'messages': [{'sender_name': 'Magda Aguilar',
   'timestamp_ms': 1692582626159,
   'content': '395',
   'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False},
  {'sender_name': 'Abigail Jackeline CG',
   'timestamp_ms': 1692582597420,
   'content': 'De que precio es ?',
   'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False},
  {'sender_name': 'Magda Aguilar',
   'timestamp_ms': 1692579131888,
   'content': 'Y me pasa sus datos',
   'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False},
```

---

y este es el codigo que he ocupado:

```
       import json
       # Carga el archivo JSON
       with open('message_1.json', 'r') as archivo: #aqui estamos cargando el archivo json
       datos = json.load(archivo)
datos
# aqui le estas dando una estructura a los datos en jason:
data = {
    'participants': [{'name': 'Abigail Jackeline CG'}, {'name': 'Magda Aguilar'}],
    'messages': [
        {
            'sender_name': 'Magda Aguilar',
            'timestamp_ms': 1692582626159,
            'content': '395',
            'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False
       },
      {
            'sender_name': 'Abigail Jackeline CG',
            'timestamp_ms': 1692582597420,
            'content': 'De que precio es ?',
            'is_geoblocked_for_viewer': False
    },  #aqui es mi duda, tendria que hacer esto por cada parrafo de conversacion de manera manual? o se pude aplicar algun bucle?
    ]
}
json_str = json.dumps(data)
parsed_data = json.loads(json_str)
print(parsed_data['participants'])
print(parsed_data['messages'])

----------------------------------------------
espero me haya dado a entender, gracias!
```